# The month starts to..?

Tags: prepositions, time

I don't know if is correct to use "the month" with "starts".

Is correct to use "to" Store or is "at" better?

Here below the phrase:

> The month of the Special Summer starts to Archivio Dondup!

Note: Archivio Dondup is the name of a store.

Comment: I think "with" might be the (or _a_) correct preposition in this case. Assuming that Archivio Dondup is some kind of store or event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the article *the* with *month*, but your sentence raises a lot of questions.

Is "Special Summer" the formal name of an event? (The capital letters make it appear that way, like it's the name of an established summer sale.)

If *Special Summer* is **not** a proper noun, I would suggest this:

> The month of summer specials starts at Archivio Dondup!

(Yes, *at* is the correct preposition to use).

If *Special Summer* **is** a proper noun, then perhaps there are better ways to write this:

> The month-long Special Summer starts at Archivio Dondup!

Also, in English, a season (such as *summer*) can be used adjectivally:

> A month of summer specials begins at Archivio Dondup!

In this case, I prefer *a* to *the*, although using *the* would not be grammatically incorrect. (Using *the* instead of *a* would suggest that you expect the readers to be familiar with the summer specials at this store, either from past years, or else from a preceding advertising blitz.)

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have a store name, the sentence would be:

> The summer starts at Archivio Dondup!

Which would imply that the store is having a summer sale or a stock full of summer products. The preposition `to` would indicate a movement to the store and is therefore wrong. `at` really means inside the store, i.e. at the store's location.

Alternatively, you could use something like the following:

> Get ready for the summer with Archivio Dondup's super summer sale!

Comment: In your opinion, is this correct?
"Get ready for the Special Summer at ... (the name of the store)!"

Comment: "Special Summer" needs to be something we know about, since it doesn't relate to the store directly. So maybe something like "Get ready for the summer with Archivio Dondup's summer collection!" or so

Comment: "[season, holiday, or event] starts at [our store]" is a fairly routine advertising slogan. I've heard that and variations on it many times.

Comment: @Jay I stand corrected – thanks! I hope you don't mind that I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ijacqu says, you wouldn't say "the summer starts to ..." "To" indicates direction or movement, and the summer isn't going anywhere. Also, "starts" doesn't take a direction.

It is fairly common to say that something "starts at ..." This is the first place where the event will happen or where it begins. You could mean this literally, like, "Summer starts at the international date line at midnight on the summer solstice." Or in this case, figuratively, you must go to this store as the first step in enjoying your summer.

You can also say "starts with ...", meaning that you need to do this thing or have this thing to start. Again, it could be literal, like "The engine starts with the press of the start button." Or figurative, "Summer starts with [our store]", meaning, our store is what you need to begin your summer, or where you go to begin your summer.

I'm not sure what you're trying to say with the word "month". You could say, "The month starts at [our store]". That's grammatically correct, but I don't know what idea it would be intended to convey. What month? What is significant about the beginning of the month? It certainly could make sense in a totally different context. Like, "At our company, the month starts with an inventory count."